# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'json'

Tags: python, json, request

I am attempting to code some auto quote image generation code using the PaperQuotes API and Pillow, but this little piece of code is screwing everything up. (I am sorry if the code is bad, I am still a newbie to coding)

Code:

```
import requests
import os

url = "https://api.paperquotes.com/apiv1/quotes/?lang=en&limit=1&offset=0&order=-likes&page=1&tags=love%2Clife%2Cdepression%2Csuicide%2Csad%2Clonely"

my_secret = os.environ['authorization']

headers = {
    'authorization': my_secret,
    }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json

info = response.json
print(info["results"])
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'json'
```

I've tried searching Stackoverflow, but I was not able to understand any of the answers I got.

Comment: You are calling `.json` twice

Comment: @Wondercricket they are actually never *calling* it, they are accessing the attribute `.json`, which is a function, which is never called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json its function, not property.
Also `info = response` because you was geted the json.

```
import requests
import os

url = "https://api.paperquotes.com/apiv1/quotes/?lang=en&limit=1&offset=0&order=-likes&page=1&tags=love%2Clife%2Cdepression%2Csuicide%2Csad%2Clonely"

my_secret = os.environ['authorization']

headers = {
    'authorization': my_secret,
    }

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()

info = response
print(info["results"])
```